# Download pyautogui, I can clearly see it in pycharm under site-packages, but when imported it gives me a no moduel under that name can be found

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

```py
    import pyautogui
```

"no module with that name is found"
the entire tree under site package is orange (Dracula theme), while all other folders are gray

I have deleted the module, installed(and reinstalled) using -m, regular ol' pip
restarted my PC, made a new project, 
I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: these links may help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using Windows 10, and I am still kinda new to Python.